# Controller mapping causing error in yii2 console application

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-user, phundament

Module section config

```
'user'  => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
            'modelMap' => [
                'User' => 'app\models\DL\User',
                'registrationForm' => 'app\models\DL\registrationForm',
            ],
            'controllerMap' => [
                /*'registration' =>    'app\controllers\user\RegistrationController',
                'admin' => 'app\controllers\user\AdminController'*/
            ],
            'layout'       => '@app/views/layouts/container',
            'defaultRoute' => 'profile',
            'admins'       => ['admin'],
            'enableFlashMessages' => false,
            'params' => [
                'menuItems'      => [
                    'label' => 'Users',
                    'url'   => ['/user/admin']
                ]
            ]
        ],
```

Yii console application (./yii) showing me error

> 'Calling unknown method:
>   app\controllers\user\AdminController::getHelpSummary()'

If I uncomment the `controllerMap` section, I can't understand why it autoloads in console app if my `AdminController` extends web controller not console.

This is commands from user module.

[image: This is commands from user module]

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the user module in console?

Yii2 console and web applications have separated configuration files by default. If you changed this default and use the same config for both of them, you must take care about consistency.

You can check the list of loaded configs in `./yii`.

Comment: I am using phundament template for yii2. https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/4.0.0-rc8/src/config/main.php. And problem is I am not able to use ./yii. It crashes straight away.

Comment: You can remove `user` module by adding override in `$console` [config](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/4.0.0-rc8/src/config/main.php#L205)

Comment: Yep, already tried it. I added screen with problem commands. If I override this module from console section, this commands will go away too.

Comment: Then you need to implement methods that are required by the console application, to get it work

Comment: Also thought about it, even tried it, turned out it's much more than pair of methods. I wonder why there is no error when same controllers are used from vendor folder. Vendor classes also don't contain those methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a valid `defaultRoute` for the console application.

With `'defaultRoute' => 'profile'`, `./yii`may try to load a `Controller` which requires the `user` module.

Try adding it in the [console configuration](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/3a6d8bca94d3b82dcb424930cd662f085eaa573d/src/config/main.php#L185).

Comment: My console section looks the same as in the link you've provided. I am using Phundament app. Or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: If it's exactly the same and your `defaultController` in `$common` is set to `profile` it also applies for the console.
Try to move the `defaultController` to [`$web`](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/3a6d8bca94d3b82dcb424930cd662f085eaa573d/src/config/main.php#L151)

Comment: Just tried it. Same effect. Only thing that helped me is moving all `controllerMap` section to web part.